# system.net.sockets and windows 10 error?

Tags: windows, system.net.sockets

I'm having a very strange problem with an application in windows 10. It consists of several .exe in the same computer communicating between them with sockets using system.net.sockets library.
The problem I have is that after installing Windows 10 in a new computer, install all windows updates and then installing that application, connection to sockets doesn't work correctly and the application fails. The strangest thing is that if you leave the computer alone for 1-2 days the applications starts working just fine. The same has happened after installing  version 1803 update, it stops working and then works one or two days later.
Any idea of what can it be? Has anyone seen something similar?

Answer (score 1):

It really seems to be related to the 1803 update you mentioned.

Symptoms:

- Running an application from a network share will fail when creating a socket;
- Copying the very same application to a local drive/path will work just fine, without any further modification.

We are also struggling with this while connecting to an Oracle database (both ODBC and ODP.NET) and it seems the issue has recently been acknowledged:

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2399465_1.html

It also seems this is a recurrent Windows bug:

- [Win Socket Creation fails with Error code 10022 if non super user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936303/win-socket-creation-fails-with-error-code-10022-if-non-super-user)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3076a9cd-57a0-418d-8de1-07adc3b486bb/socket-fails-with-error-10022-when-application-is-run-from-certain-network-shares-on-vista-and?forum=wsk

Sorry, no effective solution at the time (other than copying the app binaries to a local folder). I'll update this answer once we get a better solution.

---

OK, looking a little further I found here in SO that this might be related to a SMBv1 network share, which describes the environment we had here (the network share was disabled because of another bug we faced - thanks MSFT).

**[Re-enabling SMBv2 / SMBv3 on the server solved the issue](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-enable-disable-smbv1-smbv2-smbv3-windows-server-mohamed-salah/).**

Related post:

[After Windows 10 update 1803 my program can't open a socket when running from network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155482/after-windows-10-update-1803-my-program-cant-open-a-socket-when-running-from-ne)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this is the solution to my problem. All binaries are in the same local folder in drive C:.